# Please stop downvotes of put on hold/closed questions!

Tags: support, down-votes

I know it's duplicate , but I 'm really disappointed  with such option!

I asked Mr. Moderator to put on hold damn question in the hope it will no longer receive downvotes! 
What's the point to allow users to downvote  this question if they even no longer can answer to that question.

It's really unfair :(

Comment: Why should putting a question on hold stop downvotes?

Comment: In my view Putting on Hold  question means giving to user a chance to correct / think about the question! If this option gives a chance to think about that .. why then the "rubbish" question is open for down votes?

Comment: I'd be ok with this if putting a question on hold also stopped upvotes.

Comment: I really hope that this topic would get further push. I no longer want to use an option  "ask the question" because of such huge frustration. Thanks.

Comment: You'll get a *much* better reception if you try to address the issue constructively, rather than just ranting about your own personal issue.  Also, any suggestion that applies to downvotes needs to apply to upvotes as well.  Otherwise, you skew the quality metric.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm waiting for my supporters!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enough downvotes drives questions off the homepage.

This is beneficial, especially on smaller sites without the volume of questions that StackOverflow gets.

Some questions are just bad. Many of us have seen the "this is a drive-by question where the OP will never come back and this question is on a downvote, close, delete train" types of questions often enough to realize a downvote actually helps that process.

Comment: "Some questions are just bad" Help center material.

Comment: I always say, "People who say there are no bad questions have never visited [insert Q/A site here]". Unfortunately, including Stack Exchange sites. Difference being; We try to improve them.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to arrest and start to reverse downvotes is by editing your question to improve its quality.

Comments on your question will often indicate what is problematic about it and can help guide your edits.